# How to exponentiate the vector field $v$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, exponentiation, vector-fields

**i didn't succed to exponentiate these vector field**
$$\boxed{v=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+2b\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}}$$
where $x,y,t$ are independents variables and $u$ is an dependant variable .
this vector field is one of the basis element of a Lie algebra of symmetry associated to a certain pde .the solution of the pde is of the form $u(x,y,t)$

**Remark**:

i succeded to exponentiate the vector field $$w=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
it gives $$\exp \left(\varepsilon w\right)(x,y, t, u)=(\tilde{x},\tilde{y},\tilde{t}, \tilde{u})=\left(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\sin(\varepsilon)+(\frac{x-y}{2})\cos(\varepsilon)+(\frac{x+y}{2}),-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\sin(\varepsilon)-(\frac{x-y}{2})\cos(\varepsilon)-(\frac{x+y}{2}),t,u\right) $$
where $exp : \mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow G$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ .

to exponentiate a vector field of the form $\mathbf{v}=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=1}^{p}\xi_{k}(x,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{k}}+\sum_{i=1}^{q}\phi_{i}(x,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{i}}}$we solve the system of odes  $ \displaystyle{\frac{d\tilde{x_{i}}}{d\varepsilon}=\xi_{i}(\tilde{x_{i}})\,\,,\,\, \frac{d\tilde{u}}{d\varepsilon}=\phi(\tilde{x},\tilde{t},\tilde{y})}$ with initial conditions $\tilde{x_{i}}(0)=x_{i}$  , $\tilde{u}(0)=u$

Or we can just develop this Lie series for the flow, given by
$$
\exp (\varepsilon \mathbf{v}) \cdot x = x+\varepsilon \xi(x)+\frac{\varepsilon^2}{2} \mathbf{v}(\xi)(x)+\cdots=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\varepsilon^k}{k !} \mathbf{v}^k(x)
$$
where $\xi=\left(\xi^1, \ldots, \xi^m\right), \mathbf{v}(\xi)=\left(\mathbf{v}\left(\xi^1\right), \ldots, \mathbf{v}\left(\xi^m\right)\right)$,

**I tried to develop the serie but it's getting more and more complicated from order 3 i guess**

Thanks for the help !:)

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @TravisWillse what is the exponentiation of "v"?how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For readability, denote the initial condition by
$$(x(0), y(0), t(0), u(0)) = (x_0, y_0, t_0, u_0),$$ so that
$$(x(\tau), y(\tau), t(\tau), u(\tau)) = \exp(\tau V)(x_0, y_0, t_0, u_0) .$$

**Hint** Since the $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ components of the vector field $V$ depend only on $X, Y$, we may as well first solve for the integral curves $(x(\tau), y(\tau))$ of the projection of $V$ to the $xy$-plane, namely, $W$---that is, solve
$$x' = \sqrt{x y}, \qquad y' = -\sqrt{x y}$$
---then lift the solution curve to $xytu$-space.

We can simplify our computation some by observing that $x' + y' = 0$, hence
$x + y = x_0 + y_0$, which reduces our system to a single, separable o.d.e. in $x(t)$:
$$x' = \sqrt{x (x_0 + y_0 - x)} .$$
As in the edited question statement, solving gives
\begin{align*}
x(\tau) &= \frac{1}{2}\left[x_0 + y_0 + 2 \sqrt{x_0 y_0} \sin \tau + (x_0 - y_0) \cos \tau\right] \\
y(\tau) &= \frac{1}{2}\left[x_0 + y_0 - 2 \sqrt{x_0 y_0} \sin \tau - (x_0 - y_0) \cos \tau\right] .
\end{align*}
To compute $u(\tau)$ efficiently, we can compare coefficients of the vector find and observe that
$$u' = 2 b u x'.$$

> Integrating gives $$u(\tau) = u_0 \exp \left[2 b \left(x(\tau) - x_0\right)\right] = u_0 \exp \left[ b \left(2 \sqrt{x_0 y_0} \sin \tau + (x_0 - y_0) (\cos \tau - 1)\right) \right] .$$

Of course, since the vector field $V$ does not have a $\partial_t$-component, $t(\tau) = t_0$.

Comment: The result that I found in w is true no $exp(\epsilon w)(x,y,t,u)$ using Taylor formula instead of solving the system for ODEs ?  you used the notation $\phi$ and $\tau$  so I am little bit lost because I used them already in my work to define the vector field "the infinitesimal symmetry " associated to the pde $v=\xi(x,y,t,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+\gamma(x,y,t,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+\tau(x,y,t,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}+\phi(x,y,t,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$  in the end I think you mean by $tau$ just $\epsilon$ using the notation that I introduced in the beginning

Comment: ,also to verify we need just to derive the flow with respect to $\epsilon$ then taking $\epsilon=0$ so we can find the vector field ,from the results that you found you mean that $$\exp(\epsilon w)(x,y,t,u)=\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y).(1+\sin(\epsilon+c),\frac{1}{2}(x+y).(1-\sin(\epsilon+c),t,e^{-b}u\exp((x+y)b(1+\sin(\epsilon+c))\right)???????.$$.                                                                       with $x(0)=x$ and $y(0)=y$ also $u(0)=u$ and $\phi=c$((if we use my notations))

Comment: i made a mistake the vector field v that I defined in the first comment is $$v=\xi(x,y,t,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\gamma(x,y,t,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\tau(x,y,t,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\phi(x,y,t,u)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$$

Comment: I've tweaked the answer to make the algebraic role of the initial conditions more transparent.

Comment: normally if we derive the flow $\exp(\epsilon w)$ that you found and taking $\epsilon=0$ we need to find the vector field w , which is not the case I think !!!??   I think we need to find some $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ somewhere in the solution that you found .

Comment: For any (admissible) time $\epsilon$, $\exp(\epsilon w)$ is a (possibly only local) diffeomorphism, not a vector field, and $\exp(0)$ is the identity map on the manifold. The property that you might have in mind is $\left.\frac{d}{d\epsilon} \exp(\epsilon w)\right\vert_{\epsilon = 0} = w$.

Comment: ah okay I see , now I understand more well done !Thanks

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you found the answer helpful.

Comment: yes yes it's local , yes it's the exact property that I have in mind , I'am used to Olver's book notation that's why .